# How can I tell if a site is Legal?

Tags: support, resource

How can I tell if a site which is linked to/mentioned in a question and/or answer is a legal site?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Below is a list of sites that legally host anime or manga. When someone is reviewing questions/answers that link to/mention a site that hosts anime/manga, this list can be used to determine whether the link/mention should be kept or removed. If the site isn't listed here, then either:

1. The site is illegal and [the appropriate action stated here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/how-should-we-deal-with-new-users-posting-links-to-illegal-material-in-comments) should be taken.
2. It may have yet to be added to the list.

If you believe a site that should be on this list is missing but are unsure if it's legal or not, use the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697) (a [privilege granted at 20 reputation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat)) to discuss it or [ask on the Meta here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Illegal sites will be removed from this list. If you spot a link which may actually be illegal (and was included by mistake), edit it out of this answer and/or discuss why it was added.

This list can also be linked to when commenting on offending questions/answers to avoid any disputes.

Feel free to edit this list to keep it as up to date as possible.

---

#### Anime Streaming

- [**This Is How You Can Watch Anime Legally in 2014**](http://web.archive.org/web/20160106170549/http://organizationasg.kokidokom.net/2014/07/28/this-is-how-you-can-watch-anime-legally-in-2014/) (snapshotted 2016)
- [**Ultimate List of Legal Anime Streaming Sites & What Countries They Are Available In**](https://yattatachi.com/legal-anime-streaming-sites) (mostly up-to-date)
- [**anime-streaming - A curated list of worldwide legal anime streaming**](https://otakulogy.github.io/anime-streaming/) (mostly up-to-date)
- [Amazon Prime Video](https://www.amazon.com/anime-Prime-Video/s?k=anime&rh=n%3A2858778011)
- [Amazon Prime Video](https://www.amazon.co.jp/s/ref=atv_dp_pd_gen?rh=n:2351649051%2Cn:2478407051) (Japan)
- [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com.au/video/anime)
- [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com)
- [AnimeLab](https://www.animelab.com) (Australia)
- [Aniplex of America](https://aniplexusa.com/shows/) (more of a list of titles and streaming providers)
- [Bandai Channel](https://www.b-ch.com/)
- [Bilibili/Bstation](https://www.bilibili.tv/anime)
- [Crunchyroll](https://www.crunchyroll.com/)
- [FUNimation](https://www.funimation.com/shows/) (America)
- [HIDIVE](https://www.hidive.com/)
- [Hulu](https://www.hulu.com/) (America)
- [Hulu](https://www.hulu.jp/) (Japan)
- [Netflix](https://www.netflix.com/) (available in most countries, but content varies by region)
- [Nico Nico Douga](https://www.nicovideo.jp/)
- [RetroCrush](https://www.retrocrush.tv/) (older anime, US and Canada)
- [Sushiroll](https://sushiroll.co.id/) (Indonesia)
- [VIZ Media](https://www.viz.com/watch)
- [Wakanim](https://www.wakanim.tv/) (France)

#### YouTube Channels

- [4KidsTV Animation](https://www.youtube.com/user/4kidstv)
- [Ani-One](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0wNSTMWIL3qaorLx0jie6A)
- [Anilog (AnimeLog アニメログ)](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsnDtu-g18tDA4miToMOjXQ)
- [AniplexUS](https://www.youtube.com/user/AniplexUS)
- [BandaiChannel](https://www.youtube.com/user/BandaiChannel)
- [Funimation](https://www.youtube.com/user/FUNimation)
- [GundamInfo](https://www.youtube.com/user/GundamInfo)
- [Manga Entertainment](https://www.youtube.com/user/MANGAentertainment)
- [Muse Asia](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0wNSTMWIL3qaorLx0jie6A)

#### Manga

- [BOOK☆WALKER](https://global.bookwalker.jp/) (English service of Kadokawa Shoten)
- [ComicWalker](https://comic-walker.com/en/) (English service of Kadokawa)
- [ComicWalker](https://comic-walker.com/) (Japanese)
- [Crunchyroll](https://www.crunchyroll.com/)
- [MangaBox](https://www.mangabox.me/)
- [VIZ Media](https://www.viz.com/read)
- [Mangarock](https://mangarock.com/manga) (Provides links to legal sources in all languages)
- [MR Comics](https://mrcomics.com/) (Legal replacement of the previously illegal Mangarock)