# Off-topic reason: Requesting illegal materials is off-topic on this site

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons, off-topic

I've seen a couple of those recently, and the trend seems to be accelerating. We still have a couple more custom close reasons to spare, so I'm thinking of adding it as our second close reason.

The phrasing would be something like:

> Questions requesting **illegal copyrighted and/or licensed materials** is off-topic on our site. Please review the [help/on-topic] to *learn what kinds of questions are on-topic for [Anime & Manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com).* If you believe that your question was misinterpreted and wrongfully closed, please **edit your question** to be clearer on your intentions.

Got suggestions? Alternative wording? Too soon? Don't think it's needed? Please post it as an answer below.

Comment: I think it's weird this isn't a close reason yet.

Comment: I think we should add "illegal/pirated" (maybe fansubs, too) before "copyrighted and/or licensed materials," we're already established that "[Where to buy/watch/talk anime/manga-related media from legal sources is on-topic](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-should-we-deal-with-questions-asking-for-where-to-buy-watch-anime-or-manga)," so we don't confuse users with the wording.

Comment: @Krazer: I've edited, how's that?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha sounds good. Maybe make a note about obviously illegal pirated material, in the close reason or in the help center as it might not be readily apparent to newer users on what's legal and what's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). We went with the shorter:

> Questions **requesting illegal copyrighted and/or licensed materials** are off-topic on this site. See [How do we deal with copyrighted materials on our site?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/404) for more details.

Because the recommendation to look at the help center and to edit the question to clarify it is already inserted with every off-topic close reason.