# Can i ask a question about official western localisation of anime/manga/visual novel?

Tags: discussion

For example,

*What's happened to anime B localisation in western ? Why it got canceled ?*

Or

*What's happened to the visual novel B in western localisation ? Why it got canceled ? or why there is no update from the team after 5 years later ?*

Comment: you can even ask for a specific country! e.g. we have [india] tag and [europe] tag

Comment: While these questions are, in principle, permissible, you will almost never get a satisfying answer to any of them, because in most cases, nobody outside of the specific industry entities that were involved in the localization process will know why a localization did not proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the kind of localization (which i use loosely here).

if by localization you mean the official kind then questions like your examples fall onto the border of asking about unannounced future events (like with anime and manga). now given that both your examples ask *"Why it got canceled"* it would be on the assumption that you can provide a source that indicates that there was an announced released date and possibly also a post that says it's been canceled

If by localization you mean by fans (as *"no update from the team"* made me think of a fan translation who gives out regular updates) then generally no. while your second example question talks about a Visual Novel these would fall into the category of Scanlations and Fan Subs which has generally been (at least to my understanding) our policy of not allowing question like

> when will [scanlator] release chapter/episode # of [series]?

as these translations [according to this Anime News Network article](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/feature/2003-06-08/3) are legally in the wrong. while the [official response from SE is that Mod's aren't lawyers](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/406/1587) and thus don't need to enforce any law we don't want to do anything obviously boneheaded, as such a question like

> What's happened to *Rewrite: Harvest festa!'s* western localisation? Has it been canceled? or why there is no update from the team in Amaterasu Translations after 2 years since the site's last blog post?

would be off-topic.<sup>1</sup>. if you're not sure if a team/group are doing official or fan translations you can ask here on the Meta site or [on The Maid Cafe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697) before hand so you can avoid accidently asking something off-topic

---

<sup>1: while we would close it i would argue it if the question was self answered with a statement indicating that the fan translation stopped because of an announcement of an official translation</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the freat explanation !? (y)